# An imaginary lock mechanism: non-blocking write, read and invalidate

Tags: c++, multithreading, lock-free

Here is the scenario. Bob is a writer and Alice is a reader. Bob writes things and Alice reads them. The rules are:

1) Bob can write whether Alice is reading or not (reading does not block writes).

2) When Bob is writing, Alice cannot read (writing does block reads).

3) When Alice finishes reading, she can know if Bob wrote during her read (readers can detect if the data they just read is not valid).

2) and 3) are really one combined rule, but I list two for good discussion. The problem can be solved by one mutex and one counter (version number), but what I do not know is, is the above a well-know scenario with a commonly used name? Has any research been done on it?

Comment: may be you talk about transactions? 1. collect data 2. lock mutex 3. store 4. unlock

Comment: regarding 1) and 2): what happens when alice is reading and bob wants to write? 1) and 2) seem in contradiction in this scenario

Comment: @user5821508 For Bob, it is lock-free. So directly, storing data.

Comment: @bolov When Alice reading, Bob can write without limits, therefore Alice will get incoherent data and need to re-read, and she can know that.

Comment: @mzer0 call to ```write(data)``` is non-blocking indeed. Driver perform lock-write-unlock operation in background after returning from function

Comment: or consider this http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html

Comment: @user5821508 Thank you for your help. What I talk about is a lock mechanism more general than data structure, so boost::lockfree::queue is not actually the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Which I do not know is, is the problem a well-know scenario named by terms?

Yes, it is called Seqlock:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seqlock

> Does anyone study at it or I am just making a wheel?

AFAIK there are a variety of implementation (such as Linux kernel) and papers.

Comment: Writing doesn't (technically) block reads. It just invalidates them and a sequence number is used so readers can know if they read now invalidated data. In C++ it will take a little care with (I suggest) atomics, memory order and probably memory fences to achieve this portably. In particular the writer updates the sequence number after acquiring the lock and before releasing it. To ensure the required sequencing those operations needs to be ordered by something other than the mutex.
For single values atomics are likely a simpler/faster/more predictable option.